# Android UI Beginner question

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm new to Android/java, coming from C#/Visual Studio.
It's not a too hard jump from C# to java while coding the logic, but with the UI, I'm having problems.

I've now added a simple TextView to my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:editable="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="TextView">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I wanted to access the textView1 by code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.textView1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(android.R.id.textView1);
}
private TextView textView1;
```

but I get the error: textView1 cannot be resolved.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

James

Answer (score 2):

Replace findViewById(android.R.id.textView1) by findViewById(R.id.textView1);

android.R is resorce packege of SDK while R is of your app which will create along with successfully build of app .

and set the background color to #ffffff in xml .... it seems more attractive..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `android.R.id.textView1`, just use `R.id.textView1`. The `android` prefix is for resources from Android itself, rather than from your project.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `findViewById(android.R.id.textView1)` by `findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

android.R is resorce packege of SDK while R is of your app which will create along with successfully build of app .

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    private TextView textView1;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.textView1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setText("Hello World !!!");
   }
```